# How to save presenter instance when app process is being killed

Tags: android, mvp

Problem: Surviving app process being killed (saving presenter object instance in correct manner so it can be re-used later on)

Here is a simple example fragment which is using MVP architecture.

```
class xFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private lateinit var xPresenter: xPresenter
    override lateinit var xAdapter: BaseAdapter

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        xPresenter.view = this
        xAdapter = xAdapter(
            xPresenter,
            this,
            this
        )
        recyclerView.adapter = contentAdapter
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (xPresenter.view != null) xPresenter.view = null
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onDeleteButtonClicked() {
        x.onDeleteButtonClicked()
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun createInstance(presenter: xPresenter): xFragment {
            val fragment = xFragment()
            fragment.xPresenter = presenter
            return fragment
    }
}
```

I read that the best solution to save anything is doing it in `onPause()` and restore it in `onResume()`. As you can see, I pass my Presenter when I create my fragment in "createInstance" method. How should a save my `xPresenter` so I can retain it later on in onResume and procceed without errors?

Comment: You should not store your entire `Presenter` object, instead you can store all required variables during `onSavedInstanceState` method and retrieve it later on bundle during `onCreateView` method in fragment as `savedInstanceState`.

Answer (score 0):

If your process was killed, you can only restore things that were saved in bundle during call of [Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)). So you can't save presenter instane until it implements Serializable/Parcelable interfaces (only primitive types or serializable/parcelable objects can be stored in bundle). All saved data you could restore in [Activity.onCreate(Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) or [Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).

Comment: Well, I get an NPE when I try to access presenter, because, obv, it is not init after process is killed. How can I solve that? I could make it nullable, but still, I have to re-init later on, right?

Comment: Yes, after process was killed, you have to create presenter again. If you provide presenter from outside, so owner of that fragment should setup presenter.

Comment: One of possible solutions:
`
class Fragment {
    interface PresenterProvider {
        val presenter: Presenter
    }

    private fun getPresenter(): Presenter {
         if(activity is PresenterProvider) {
             return activity.presenter
         } else {
             throw IllegalStateException("Owner should implement PresenterProvider")
         }
    }
}
`
If your owner is other fragment, you should add special check for targetFragment and parentFragment and implement PresenterProvider on owner fragment (fragment that performs transaction on it's FragmentManager).